# Django custom view of a third party app

Tags: django, view, module

Lets say I have installed a 3rd party app called 'articles', the app contains basic templates and views. And there is a view called 'home' to list articles.

I need to add a form within that view and of course the form variable is not in the default 'home' view. How should I go about adding the form variable to that view?

There are a couple of ways I can think of right now:

1. Create another app and create a custom view.
2. This seems crazy and I won't do it, but for the sake of possibility, add a context processor to add the form variable into the context.

Just wondering if anyone had this situation and what is the best approach for this?

Comment: why not create another view, then the new view inherit the `home` view. That way you can user `super` and then add any context

Answer (score 0):

well, you may want to try a Function Decorator to redefine the previous view function.
the context processor or the middlerware is not recommend because it's global and dirty.

another use way I can thing is use-defined tags. This may takes more affort and go against the origin design of the tags. But it seem to be a good way.